# Sublime TextEditor 2 in Vintage mode completion

Tags: sublime-text-2, c++, clang

I have several problem with my autocompletion which I want to fix:

1. I have completion by Space. I want that when I press Space means I don't want completion I want a space symbol now.
2. I want to choose a completion of a word by Tab, it is possible in SE2, but the completion popup list is closing when Tab is pressed. I want to see avoid closing in this case.
3. How to make popup list window bigger?
4. I use SublimeClang and the completion is very lagging (despite Core i7 3rd gen with 8G Memory). I know this plugin has fast_completion mode, but it is very bad, so that there is no sense in this completion at all. How to make this plugin to show the last parsing result of completion and prepare new result in another tread?